# A good reference for the fact that "Set of continuously differentiable, square integrable functions with a compact support is dense on $L^2$"

Tags: real-analysis

While reading "Robust Statistics" by Huber, I saw that he wrote (I am paraphrasing):

> The set of square integrable, continuously differentiable, compactly
>   supported functions is dense on the set of square integrable
>   functions.

I am to use this fact in a paper that I am writing but, as the readers are mostly going to be engineers, I feel like I need a good reference. I have looked around but cannot find a book that has this exact form of the fact.

Could you please help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first "square integrable" is not needed, as it follows from the other hypotheses. If you replace "continuously differentiable" by "continuous," the result is in many texts. You can derive the continuously diff. case from this

Comment: For engineers you can just define $L^2$ as the completion (limits of Cauchy sequences) for the $L^2$ norm of the set of $L^2$ continuous functions, so they are dense by definition. The only subtlety is that such a limit of Cauchy sequence can be represented by a function (no need of things like $\delta$ and $pv(1/x)$)

Comment: Is there ever a case for needing bad references?

Comment: A fairly standard reference would be Rudin's "Real & Complex Analysis", Theorem 3.14.

Comment: Thanks. As a follow-up, what would be the best citation for Stone-Weierstrass Theorem?